# Executing code on server while shutting down the computer

Tags: python, server, gpu, scheduled-tasks

I have Python code that I want to run on a GPU server. Running it is time-consuming and sometimes, I get disconnected from the Internet or server and I have to re-run it. So, I need to let it run and shut down my computer. Is there any way?

Comment: You can use [`screen`](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-linux-screen/) to solve this issue.

Comment: SO probably isn't a great resource for this. You want a tool like `screen` (as mentioned), or `tmux`. You can also use `nohup` with process management to run the process in the background, even when disconnected. Also, a tool like `mosh` might help if you're losing an SSH connection. You might also consider `cron` if it's going to be run often. Or some combination of all of the above.

Comment: Thanks. If I am not allowed to use "sudo" on the server, is there any script or piece of code that helps?

Comment: Yes.  Most of the tools listed can be run without sudo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `screen` to maintain a session and achieve the goal that allows you to run the code on the server.

Refer to this: https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/

Some basic commands:

- Create session named RunWork

```
screen -S RunWork
```

- List all sessions:

```
screen -ls
```

- Open a session

```
screen -r SessionID
```

...

Answer (score 0):

If it is a windows server create a bat file.
Run the python script and the shutdown command. You will have to be an admin to shutdown the computer from a script.

bat file

c:\python27\python.exe c:\somescript.py %*

shutdown /s /f /t 0

Comment: why is the `shutdown` command necessary? what do the arguments do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are Linux-based OS then Tmux can help you.

> Tmux is a terminal multiplexer. It lets you switch easily between several programs in one terminal, detach them (they keep running in the background) and reattach them to a different terminal.

https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki